# Push Array In Fusionchart JSON Formar

Tags: javascript, php, ajax, codeigniter, fusioncharts

i want to put my data that i get from database into Fusionchart JSON , its stacked type chart . i want to put variable $data into category not categories.

i have tried using push array but data not in the where it should be,

```
$charts = array(
      'chart' => 
      array(
        'caption' => 'Sales Performance Indicator',
        'subcaption' => 'By Plan & Achievement',
        'numvisibleplot' => '6',
        'showvalues' => '1',
        'decimals' => '1',
        'stack100percent' => '1',
        'valuefontcolor' => '#FFFFFF',
        'plottooltext' => '$label has $dataValue ($percentValue) 
$seriesName sales product',
        'theme' => 'zune',
      ),
      'categories' => 
      array(
        array(
            'category' =>
                    array(
                         0 => 
            array (
              'label' => 'Farid',
            ),
            1 => 
            array (
              'label' => 'Erna',
            ),
            2 => 
            array (
              'label' => 'Dudi',
            ),
            3 => 
            array (
              'label' => 'Yudha',
            ),
            4 => 
            array (
              'label' => 'Ahmad',
            ),
            )
        )
      ),

foreach ($query->result() as $val) {
         $data = array('label' => $val->name);
         $charts["categories"][] = $data;
    }
```

please help

Comment: Can you give more information, i really am not sure what you are trying to do

Comment: how to push $data variable into category array, it's core problem ...

Comment: `category` or `categories`? If it's the first one then you missed one level: `$charts["categories"]['category'][]`

Comment: @Dharman let me try first

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is not a perfect way of doing it. But does it do the job?

```
                 $charts = array(
                  'chart' => 
                  array(
                    'caption' => 'Sales Performance Indicator',
                    'subcaption' => 'By Plan & Achievement',
                    'numvisibleplot' => '6',
                    'showvalues' => '1',
                    'decimals' => '1',
                    'stack100percent' => '1',
                    'valuefontcolor' => '#FFFFFF',
                    'plottooltext' => '$label has $dataValue ($percentValue) 
            $seriesName sales product',
                    'theme' => 'zune',
                  ),
                  'categories' => 
                  array(
                    array(
                        'category' =>
                                array(
                                     0 => 
                        array (
                          'label' => 'Farid',
                        ),
                        1 => 
                        array (
                          'label' => 'Erna',
                        ),
                        2 => 
                        array (
                          'label' => 'Dudi',
                        ),
                        3 => 
                        array (
                          'label' => 'Yudha',
                        ),
                        4 => 
                        array (
                          'label' => 'Ahmad',
                        ),
                        )
                    )
                  ),
              );

        $data = array(
            "stuff" => 1,
            "items" => 2,
        );


        array_push($charts['categories'][0]['category'], $data);
        print_r($charts);
```

Comment: it's different , output from you "categories":[{"category":[{"label":"Icha","items":"Rahma"}]}] ,, but it should be : [{"category":[{"label":"Icha"},{"label":"Icha"}]}]